# Building a particle accelerator with Cathode Ray tube

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, electronics

I was thinking of simple ways to create a particle accelerator and I thought of using a cathode ray tube and sending electrons through it. I would have to apply a lot of voltage so the electrons could smash. My description of the accelerator is down below. My question is would this work? I am not expecting anyhting big like LHC but would this work at all?[image]

Comment: The chance of two electrons colliding head on is so low with such low quality apparatus.

Comment: I would not even try risking anything using high voltage, it's not worth it, unless you know exactly what you are doing. People have posted about taking their TV apart, it's not recommended, to say the least.

Comment: http://www.scienceinschool.org/2014/issue30/accelerator might interest you